# Instruments stopped working after downgraded Xcode 5 to Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios7, instruments

after I downgraded my Xcode from Xcode5 to Xcode4, my instruments stopped working. It actually works when I run in the simulator but in my device it fails to run.

when I run Instruments on my project, I get this screen:
[image]

Instruments tries to start the app but it gets no data from it and the running process stays paralized.

It happenad after I uninstalled Xcode5 and reinstalled Xcode 4.6.3. I also tried to Xcode 4.6.2 but nothing came to happen. I am using OS Mountain Lion 10.8.5 and the iPhone iOS 7.0

Comment: Did you try calling xcode-select on the old xcode?

Comment: It is printing the correct path to my installed Xcode:
$ xcode-select -print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: What is on your device in terms of the iOS environment?

Comment: Same problem. App blocked on main screen on iPhone and nothing is recorded on instruments. I'm using iPhone 4 ios 7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this way:

1. In practice, Instruments never worked (for me) to test an app running in a device that has a SDK newer than that Xcode's default one. Therefore, I installed the newest Xcode and now I am able to run instruments on the newest iPhone SDK.
2. **Why was I using an older version of Xcode?** Because I was willing to compile to an old SDK version (older than the iOS SDK 7.0), once the Xcode5 comes with only the iOS SDK 7.0.
3. **So what did I do to compile with the iOS 6.1 SDK in Xcode5?** I Installed a previews version of the iOS SDK in the Xcode 5. So I selected the SDK version as 6.1 instead of the iOS 7.0
4. **How to install older SDK to the newest Xcode?**

   - 4.a. U can get the iOS 6.1 SDK from
     http://www.4shared.com/zip/NlPgsxz6/iPhoneOS61sdk.html or downloading
     an older Xcode and geting the SDK from its contents
   - 4.b. Unzip and paste this folder to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
   - 4.c. Restart the xcode.
   - 4.d. U can now select an older SDK on your project's build settings